# Goroutine does not execute if time.Sleep included

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

The following code runs perfectly fine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func my_func(c chan int){
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}

func main(){
    c := make(chan int)
    go my_func(c)

    c<-3
}
```

[playgound_1](https://play.golang.org/p/A1iylDEsv1)

However if I change

```
c<-3
```

to

```
time.Sleep(time.Second)
c<-3
```

[playground_2](https://play.golang.org/p/ZjoYbY2xQ3)

My code does not execute.

My gut feeling is that somehow `main` returns before the `my_func` finishes executing, but it seems like adding a pause should not have any effect. I am totally lost on this simple example, what's going on here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When the `main` function ends, the program ends with it. It does not wait for other goroutines to finish.

Quoting from the [Go Language Specification: Program Execution](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution):

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function `main`. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-`main`) goroutines to complete.

So simply when your `main` function succeeds by sending the value on the channel, the program might terminate immediately, before the other goroutine has the chance to print the received value to the console.

If you want to make sure the value gets printed to the console, you have to synchronize it with the event of exiting from the `main` function:

Example with a "done" channel (try it on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/539XE6MxvN)):

```
func my_func(c, done chan int) {
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    done <- 1
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    done := make(chan int)
    go my_func(c, done)

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    c <- 3
    <-done
}
```

Since `done` is also an unbuffered channel, receiving from it at the end of the `main` function must wait the sending of a value on the `done` channel, which happens after the value sent on channel `c` has been received and printed to the console.

**Explanation for the seemingly non-deterministic runs:**

Goroutines may or may not be executed parallel *at the same time*. Synchronization ensures that certain events happen before other events. That is the only guarantee you get, and the only thing you should rely on.
2 examples of this *Happens Before*:

> - The `go` statement that starts a new goroutine happens before the goroutine's execution begins.
> - A send on a channel happens before the corresponding receive from that channel completes.

For more details read [**The Go Memory Model**](http://golang.org/ref/mem).

**Back to your example:**

> A receive from an unbuffered channel happens before the send on that channel completes.

So the only guarantee you get is that the goroutine that runs `my_func()` will receive the value from channel `c` sent from `main()`. But once the value is received, the `main` function *may* continue but since there is no more statements after the send, it simply ends - along with the program. Whether the non-`main` goroutine will have *time* or *chance* to print it with `fmt.Println()` is *not defined*.

Comment: Can you explain why in my first example `my_func` finishes before main ends, but not in the second example?

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but might be better if some info was added re: a way (or ways) to get the example code to wait ...

Comment: Added explanation and an example how to make sure the value sent on the channel gets printed.

Comment: I think I get it, but I want to make sure. Is my understanding correct: "both first and second example, my goroutine might or might not be able to complete before main finishes, and the fact that it happens in first example and not second is just pure chance.

Comment: @Akavall Yes, in both of those cases the value might or might not get printed. Note that on the Go Playground the results of programs are cached. So if in one case it gets printed, running the same program will always print it (until someone deletes the output caches of the programs).