# How can wait for more than one goroutine to finish?

Tags: go, goroutine, barrier

```
package main

var fooRunning = false
var barRunning = false

func foo() {
    fooRunning = true
    defer func() { fooRunning = false }()
    if barRunning {
        // wait for bar() to finish
    }
    ...
}

func bar() {
    barRunning = true
    defer func() { barRunning = false }()
    if fooRunning {
        // wait for foo() to finish
    }
    ...
}
```

In my case if we run `go foo()` it should wait for `bar()` to finish and vice versa. What is the best way to do it? Note that they also can be executed independently.

Comment: Related / Possible duplicate of [What's wrong with this golang code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958192/whats-wrong-with-this-golang-code?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Those requirements lead to a huge number of race conditions that must be properly handled (What if the other routine ends right after your postitive check  ? What if someone else starts the other routine right after a negative check etc. What if someone runs 2 routines of foo() )  I would strongly urge you to create a better design where you don't have 2 goroutines that are mutually dependent on the otherwise independent running state of the other.

Comment: The code in the question has a designed deadlock as @nos noted. There is no solution that will work to the given scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements cannot be satisfied safely by any concrete design. As prescribed, you say that `foo` and `bar` **can** run in concurrent goroutines, and that if either or both of them have started, the other should wait for them both to finish. That is too weak of a prescription, though; what happens if `foo` starts and then would finish, but `bar` hasn't started running yet? What if `bar` never runs at all? Or what if `bar` runs, but `foo` never does?

Are you mandating that both `foo` and `bar` must start and complete in order for your program to be correct? If so, I can guess as to what you meant to prescribe: You want a [*barrier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)) that waits for them both to complete before proceeding.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func foo() {
    fmt.Println("foo")
}

func bar() {
    fmt.Println("bar")
}

func within(wg *sync.WaitGroup, f func()) {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        f()
    }()
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    within(&wg, foo)
    within(&wg, bar)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Both foo and bar completed.")
}
```

*([That same example in the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DIzqoIFnhXG))*

Note that here, neither `foo` nor `bar` are mutually aware; only their callers are, in the interest of coordinating the two calls.

Your original attempt might lead you down the road of making `foo` and `bar` each close over or accept as a parameter a `sync.WaitGroup`, with each function first [adding itself to the group](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Add) and [waiting on it](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Wait) before exiting. That way lies madness.

If `foo` starts and completes before `bar` has a chance to add itself to the `WaitGroup`, `foo` will exit before `bar`, even though you could claim they had been running concurrently, or the converse with `bar` running before `foo` can register its active state. Again, since this is a poorly specified aspect of your program, I suggest you instead focus on a higher-level barrier and not on the mutual dependence of these two functions.

Comment: We should always pass pointers for sync.WaitGroup. The playground also suggests the same.

Comment: Thanks, @SouravPrem. I updated the text here and the Playground link per your advice.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a channel! As i remember from my rusty go, this would give:

```
func foo() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go bar(c)
    <-c
}
```

and in bar

```
func bar(c chan int) {
    // do stuff here
    c <- 0
}
```

Comment: What if bar() not running? Channel will block further execution, right?

Comment: Yes, unless another goroutine pushes an integer in the channel, the `<-c` will block until further integers are given. If you forget to give an integer to the channel in `bar` then your program will run into a deadlock

Comment: This only provides unidirectional blocking, where the question wanted bidirectional; it doesn't address the designed deadlock in the question; and it uses channels unnecessarily. [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) is built for exactly this use case, but a solution can't be proposed until the deadlock is removed from the design.