# Run multiple functions concurrently at intervals in Go

Tags: go, timer, scheduler

I have a list of functions and their respective intervals. I want to run each function at its interval concurrently.

In JavaScript, I wrote something like:

```
maps.forEach(({fn, interval}) => {
    setInterval(fn, interval)
})
```

How do I implement this functionality in Golang?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker

Comment: Hey Peter, I know of the ticker function. My problem is in looping the tickers concurrently.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Just a nit-pick: nothing runs concurrently in JS

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a [`time.Ticker`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker) to receive "events" periodically, which you may use to time the execution of a function. You may obtain a `time.Ticker` by calling [`time.NewTicker()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker). The returned ticker has a channel on which values are sent periodically.

Use a goroutine to continuously receive the events and call the function, e.g. with a `for range` loop.

Let's see 2 functions:

```
func oneSec() {
    log.Println("oneSec")
}

func twoSec() {
    log.Println("twoSec")
}
```

Here's a simple scheduler that periodically calls a given function:

```
func schedule(f func(), interval time.Duration) *time.Ticker {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(interval)
    go func() {
        for range ticker.C {
            f()
        }
    }()
    return ticker
}
```

Example using it:

```
func main() {
    t1 := schedule(oneSec, time.Second)
    t2 := schedule(twoSec, 2*time.Second)
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    t1.Stop()
    t2.Stop()
}
```

Example output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gKAGyVLWqQ6)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:01 oneSec
2009/11/10 23:00:02 twoSec
2009/11/10 23:00:02 oneSec
2009/11/10 23:00:03 oneSec
2009/11/10 23:00:04 twoSec
2009/11/10 23:00:04 oneSec
```

Note that `Ticker.Stop()` does not close the ticker's channel, so a `for range` will not terminate; `Stop()` only stops sending values on the ticker's channel.

If you want to terminate the goroutines used to schedule the function calls, you may do that with an additional channel. And then those goroutines may use a `select` statement to "monitor" the ticker's channel and this `done` channel, and return if receiving from `done` succeeds.

For example:

```
func schedule(f func(), interval time.Duration, done <-chan bool) *time.Ticker {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(interval)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                f()
            case <-done:
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    return ticker
}
```

And using it:

```
func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    t1 := schedule(oneSec, time.Second, done)
    t2 := schedule(twoSec, 2*time.Second, done)
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    close(done)
    t1.Stop()
    t2.Stop()
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/L9LiFlc87jo).

Note that even though stopping the tickers is not necessary in this simple example (because [when the `main` goroutine ends, so does the program with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958192/no-output-from-goroutine-in-go/28958240#28958240)), in real-life examples if the app continues to run, leaving the tickers unstopped wastes resources (they will continue to use a background goroutine, and will continue to try to send values on their channels).

**Last words:**

If you have a slice of function-interval pairs, simply use a loop to pass each pair to this `schedule()` function. Something like this:

```
type pair struct {
    f        func()
    interval time.Duration
}

pairs := []pair{
    {oneSec, time.Second},
    {twoSec, 2 * time.Second},
}

done := make(chan bool)
ts := make([]*time.Ticker, len(pairs))
for i, p := range pairs {
    ts[i] = schedule(p.f, p.interval, done)
}

time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
close(done)

for _, t := range ts {
    t.Stop()
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5lCpDYrYJ9A).

Comment: All good and fine. But in my case, I have a list of n items, where each item is a function-interval pair. For each item, I want to spin up a goroutine calling the function at its interval.

Comment: @ChidiWilliams So call this `schedule()` function, passing each of your functions and their intervals, you may use a loop for that.

Comment: Alright thanks. I came up with this: https://play.golang.org/p/HogqmrdYDSk. Could you add a loop over an array like that in your answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: @icza "in real-life examples if the app continues to run, leaving the tickers unstopped wastes resources (they will continue to use a background goroutine" - isn't that the idea of a ticker? to run forever periodically until the program exits, like cron? And if the ticker's background routine is always kept alive, won't this cause a memory leak/goroutine leak when we use tickers intended to run forever?

Comment: @scc A ticker's lifetime is not necessarily the app's lifetime. If not, you may use `Ticker.Stop()` to clean its resources. If you don't do it, you won't notice anything with a single ticker. If you create thousands or a million tickers and you don't stop them, you'll notice. But obviously it's good practice to stop a ticker once you don't use it, so if you (or someone else) later extends your code, it won't end up leaking resources if your code is put into a loop.

Comment: @scc If you have a long-running ticker, there is no leaking memory. There are (may be) some shared goroutines in the background that coordinate tickers and try to send on their channels when the time comes, but this doesn't include / mean memory leaking. What may be a leak is if you have an (endless) loop creating tickers and not stopping them. Each new ticker adds some task to the background coordinators, and it'll just keep growing. `Stop()` properly cleans that out.

Comment: @icza Was thinking of the situation where a ticker is intended to run while the program itself runs but that may not always be the case of course. When we do want a cron like ticker - or multiple, eg 10 to run a task every hour - is the best option to create the 10 tickers upfront and keep them forever, or should we stop and create a new one (all 10 in our example) on each cycle/every hour so it freeds associated resources? Used for-loops/goroutines/sleep for the same effect and see a slight memory increase every hour so was thinking of replacing with tickers and wondering on the best approach

Comment: @scc If you need a ticker for long time (hours) or even for the lifetime of the app, then don't stop it, create it once and just leave it running. There's nothing wrong with that. There is no memory leak in that. A ticker's memory usage will not grow over time. All I'm saying is stop a ticker once you don't need it.