# Can buffered channel of size 1 give one delayed send of guarantee?

Tags: go, channel

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/ardanlabs/gotraining/tree/master/topics/go/concurrency/channels#signaling-with-or-without-data):
Buffered channel of size 1 can give you one delayed send of guarantee

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func display(ch chan int) {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(<-ch) // Receiving data
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 1) // Buffered channel - Send happens before receive
    go display(ch)
    fmt.Printf("Current Unix Time: %v\n", time.Now().Unix())
    ch <- 1 // Sending data
    fmt.Printf("Data sent at: %v\n", time.Now().Unix())
}
```

---

Output:

```
Current Unix Time: 1610599724
Data sent at: 1610599724
```

Does buffered channel of size 1, guarantee the receiving of data, if not displaying the data in the above code?

How to verify, if `display()` received data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958192/no-output-from-goroutine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can guarantee the receiving goroutine received data is tell the caller that it did:

```
func display(ch chan int,done chan struct{}) {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(<-ch) // Receiving data
    close(done)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 1) // Buffered channel - Send happens before receive
    done:=make(chan struct{})
    go display(ch,done)
    fmt.Printf("Current Unix Time: %v\n", time.Now().Unix())
    ch <- 1 // Sending data
    fmt.Printf("Data sent at: %v\n", time.Now().Unix())
    <-done
   // received data
}
```

You can also use a `sync.WaitGroup` for the same purpose.

Comment: For your point: "only way you can guarantee the receiving goroutine received data". Can't unbuffered channel gurantee receive? as shown here https://play.golang.org/p/LWE_BREje4C

Comment: In an unbuffered channel, write implies read happened. Not so in a buffered channel.

Comment: `close(done)` is not a guranteed delivery, because signal send happens before signal receive, for `done`, if you see the timestamps, as shown here: https://play.golang.org/p/0sG0-S5ev9t

Comment: `<-done` returning implies `close(done)` is completed. That doesn't imply the timestamps are printed in the order you want.  Both goroutines are still working. You cannot tell which goroutine will print the timestamp first.

Comment: Just comment (`// <-done`) code works, Isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: For your point: "tell the caller that it did" using `close(done)`, am saying that `close(done)` is not a guaranteed delivery.

Comment: How so? In this case, it is guaranteed, because of the read from the channel in the main goroutine.

Comment: The moment `<-done` returns, you are sure that `close` is called. How is that not guaranteed delivery?

Comment: Just verify by this line: `// <-done`. `close(done) //  var done chan struct{}` does not block  `display()`, where as `done <- 1  //  var done chan int` blocks `display()`

Comment: Just to be clear: your initial question is about making sure `display` received the data in the buffered channel. When `<-done` returns in main, you can be sure that `display` received that. There is no need for `display` to be blocked.

Comment: I understand this point, but let me accept your answer