# Data race in Go: Why does it happen below 10-11ms?

Tags: go, data-race

Here is the code I ran:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const delay = 9 * time.Millisecond

func main() {
    n := 0
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(delay)
        n++
    }()
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

Here is the command I used:

```sh
go run -race data_race_demo.go
```

Here is the behavior I noticed:

- With `delay` set to 9ms or lower, data race is always detected (program throws `Found 1 data race(s)`)
- With `delay` set to 12ms or higher, data race is never detected (program simply prints `0`)
- With `delay` set to 10 to 11ms, data race occurs intermittently (that is, sometimes prints `0` and sometimes throws `Found 1 data race(s)`)

Why does this happen **at around 10-11ms**?

I'm using Go 1.16.3 on `darwin/amd64`, if that matters.

Comment: "With delay set to 12ms or higher, data race is never detected" Which means nothing: The race is still present.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 2 goroutines: the `main` and the one you launch. They access the `n` variable (and one is a write) without synchronization: that's a data race.

Whether this race is detected depends on whether this racy access occurs. [When the `main()` function ends, your app ends as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958192/no-output-from-goroutine/28958240#28958240), it does not wait for other non-`main` goroutines to finish.

If you increase the sleep delay, `main()` will end sooner than the end of sleep and will not wait for the `n++` racy write to occur, so nothing is detected. If sleep is short, shorter than the `fmt.Prinln()` execution time, the racy write occurs and is detected.

There's *nothing* special about the 10ms. That's just the approximated time it takes to execute `fmt.Println()` and terminate your app in *your* environment. If you do other "lengthy" task before the `Println()` statement, such as this:

```
for i := 0; i < 5_000_000_000; i++ {
}
fmt.Println(n)
```

The race will be detected even with 50ms sleep too (because that loop will take some time to execute, allowing the racy write to occur before `n` is read for the `fmt.Println()` call and the app terminated). (A simple `time.Sleep()` would also do, I just didn't want anyone to draw the wrong conclusion that they "interact" with each other somehow.)

Comment: Thanks. But, what's so special about 10ms?

Comment: @ManuManjunath There's _nothing_ special about 10ms. That's just the time it takes to execute `fmt.Println()` and terminate your app in _your_ environment.

Comment: You don't even have to do anything before the `fmt.Println`, just allowing the goroutine to run before exiting will show the race, even if you wait multiple seconds between the read and write.