# Synchronizing with a GO waitgroup

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

Why is this a deadlock in example 1, and does not deadlock nor print anything in example 2 ?

Example 1.)

```
func main() {

    w := sync.WaitGroup{}
    w.Add(4)
    c := make(chan int)

    go func() { c <- 1; w.Done() }()
    go func() { c <- 2; w.Done() }()
    go func() { c <- 3; w.Done() }()

    go func() { println(len(c)); w.Done() }()

    w.Wait()
}
```

Example 2.)

```
func main() {
    w := sync.WaitGroup{}
    w.Add(3)
    c := make(chan int)

    go func() { c <- 1; w.Done() }()
    go func() { c <- 2; w.Done() }()
    go func() { c <- 3; w.Done() }()

    go func() { w.Wait(); println(len(c)) }()
}
```

Comment: 1st) there are no receivers for the unbuffered channel `c`, so deadlock 2nd) it serves no purpose as your program exits, soon after the goroutines are scheduled (nothing happens)

Comment: It steel deadlock, but not happen in main goroutine

Comment: Buffered the channel in example 1: https://go.dev/play/p/xQd43TFvNER

Comment: Move "waiter" to main goroutine in example 2: https://go.dev/play/p/zM_tgqMpvGM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, the channels won't be able to send since there is no receiver on the other end of the unbuffered channel. The sent will block forever. And therefore the waitgroup will wait forever. This is a deadlock situation as your program is not able to continue at all.

In the second case, the same thing happens, but you wait in a separate goroutine. So the main function is able to continue. It's not a complete deadlock. In this case, the continuation means the program just exists.

Comment: Ok so channels must have a receiver - did not know that!

Comment: They must have a receiver, if they are unbuffered. This is an important sync mechanism. If you do not want them to block until it has been received, you need to use a buffered channel.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example launches 3 goroutines, and each tries to send a value on the `c` unbuffered channel. Since no one receives from the channel, all these will block. So the `main()` waiting for them to complete, will also be blocked. All goroutines are blocked: deadlock.

In your second example the `main()` function "just" launches goroutines and does not do anything after that. And when the `main` goroutine finishes (when your `main()` function returns), your app ends as well, it does not wait for other non-`main` goroutines to finishes. For details, see [No output from goroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958192/no-output-from-goroutine/28958240#28958240).