# Go: invoking methods concurrently isn't working for me

Tags: methods, concurrency, go

I'm new to Go. I'm trying out this example where I want to perform a concurrent call from a method. This isn't working for me (I don't see the output).

Based on "Effective Go", it says concurrency is supported for methods and functions. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
-Srikanth

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Hello struct {
    a int
}

func (h *Hello) Myprint (value string) {
    go func() {
        fmt.Println(value)
    } ()
}

func main() {
    h := &Hello{100}

    go h.Myprint("need to go")
}
```

Comment: Your program exits before the goroutine manages to start

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307783/goroutine-does-not-execute-if-time-sleep-included

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` exits and the process dies before the goroutine has a chance to print the output.