# Go routine to download from a URL to a file

Tags: go, goroutine

I am currenlty learning GO. After learning some of the basics I have been trying to write a small program that concurrently download webpages (urls in a slice) to different files using goroutines. Here is some code that I wrote:

```
func downloadFromUrl(url string) {
    tokens := strings.Split(url, "/")
    fileName := tokens[len(tokens)-1]
    // I took out the bit that download the file for testing.
    fmt.Println("Downloading", url, "to", fileName)

}
```

I commented out the bit that actually downloads the page for testing. In my main function I am doing this:

```
func main() {
    urls := []string{"http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.google.com"}

    for _, url := range urls {
        fmt.Println(url);
        go downloadFromUrl(url);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I use the expression `go downloadFromUrl(url);` The function downloadFromUrl does not run. But if I just use `downloadFromUrl(url)` in the loop it works fine. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to use channel with the routines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of 1. [Whats wrong with this golang code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958192/whats-wrong-with-this-golang-code) 2. [Goroutine does not execute if time.Sleep included](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307783/goroutine-does-not-execute-if-time-sleep-included)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is main exits before your goroutine returns, the easiest solution is to use a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

```
func main() {
    urls := []string{"http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.google.com"}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, url := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        log.Println(url)
        go downloadFromUrl(url, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func downloadFromUrl(url string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ....
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works for me. but can you explain how this works? or refer me to the appropriate documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @awm when you do `go func()` it runs in the background and execution continues, so basically main() ends because there's nothing running in it. Using a waitgroup will force main to wait.